# Which SLDS CSS code is used to hide error text on file upload pop up?

Tags: css, slds, experience-cloud, fileupload, slds-styling-hooks

Our client's Experience Cloud site has some CSS code that another consultant implemented, but since I cannot get in touch with them, I hope any of you can help me out.

I am trying to figure out how to make the default error texts re-appear in our Experience Cloud File upload block.

We have a limit of 25 MB as file upload size on our Partner and our Customer Site. If I upload the exact same file I can see the error code on the Partner portal (there is no CSS set here)

[image: Image example 1]

However when i do the same on our Customer Site, I do not get the red text:

[image: Image example 2]

How can I make the text that is invisible on the second image, visible again? Which SLDS codes are used for this in CSS?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Have figured this out with the help of other community members, so for others in the future, here's the code that was hiding this text:

.slds-text-body_small, .slds-text-body--small {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
      visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LWC, you can use `setCustomValidity` method on it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/specification